# Cross domain origin issue for Iframe in my WordPress site

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, iframe, cross-domain

I have integrated third party API in my WordPress site. While using that API, a frame loaded in my page. At the same time I got the following JavaScript error in my console,

```
##Failed to execute 'post Message' on ' Document Object Model Window  ': The target origin provided ('://xxx.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('://xxx.com').##
```

After that I can't execute next JavaScript function.

How to resolve that error ?

Please give me solution.

Comment: Please add the code for your javascript to the question.

Comment: That is iframe(other site) javascript code, We can't edit that code....I think have cross domain issue.

Comment: Moby M ..Thanks for your correction..